# Why does the phenomenon mass deficit even occur?

Tags: nuclear-physics, mass-energy, binding-energy

I know that the missing mass is converted to energy through the use of this relation: $E=mc^2$

But, my question is why?

Answer (score 0):

Nuclear binding energy is the minimum energy that is needed to disassemble the nucleus into its constituents. There is binding energy, and we need to spend energy to move these parts (nucleons) away from each other, attracted by the strong nuclear force. The mass of the nucleus is less then the sum of the masses of the free constituent parts (neutrons and protons), this missing energy is the mass defect and represents the energy that was released when the nucleus was formed.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy

You are asking why this is necessary. Without this, nuclei could not be formed, and the mass energy equivalence would not hold.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence

Without this, the atoms around us could not form, and the matter we know could not exist.